# Autofac, thread and ISErviceScopeFactory

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem: the service provider is disposed when arrives in the method.
Is this an issue or it is my fault?

My service

```
public class BomService
{
  private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scope;

  public BomService(IServiceScopeFactory scope)
  {
      _scope = scope;
  }

  public void ImportAsync(ImportRequestDto importSettings)
  {
       Task.Run(async () => await ImportFile.ImportAsync<Bom, CatalogContext>(_scope));
  }
}
```

Method

```
public static async Task ImportAsync<T, TContext>(IServiceScopeFactory parentScope) where T : class where TContext : DbContext
{
     using var scope = parentScope.CreateScope();
     var repo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IGenericRepository<T, TContext>>();
}
```

The error:

```
Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it has already been disposed
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not run long running tasks in an HTTP request, these should be done in a separate process while returning a response to the client immediately.

Refer to the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944538/prevent-iis-from-idle-timeout-when-running-background-tasks/59949887#59949887)

As also suggested there you can use something like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) to run background processes.

**Update**
It is not good practice to inject IServiceScopeFactory. Like that you are implementing the Service Locator anti pattern. Instead inject the repository directly and let the DI figure out the resolution and scope.

Comment: I don't want to use Hangfire to do a thing that I could do myself. Task.Run() does the same of BackgroundJob.Enque(). Is a fire and forget on a separate thread. Now I update the questione because the problem is Autofac