# Background Service in Singleton Scope

Tags: c#, cron, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

in my rested-web-service project, i need to check database in one hour intervals, this method should continue to work all the time, even if there is not user, and this method is single per hosted server.(some thing like cron in linux but i will host is iis)

i have created a hostedService [using microsft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio),
with merely modifying the execute intervals (from 5 sec to 1 hours),

**but problem occure after i deploy webservice solution in iis,this hosted servicerun if swagger page is open when i close browser or not calling rest-service, there is no logs in database

another problem is if a open if i open swagger ui and call webservices from mobile-client there is multiple logs instead of only one per hour.**

i bellive there is two problem here, first TimedHostedService scope is not singleton and it is created per request(scoped) and second problem is application is not kept alive where there is not any session in swagger-ui (or there is no user for werb services).

i hava tried creating Async Method for this purpose that method call-it self with task.delay(onHour)
but this didnt work either.

```
public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private int executionCount = 0;
    private readonly ILogger<TimedHostedService> _logger;
    private Timer? _timer = null;

    public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object? state)
    {
        var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref executionCount);

        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {Count}", count);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944538/prevent-iis-from-idle-timeout-when-running-background-tasks might help?

Comment: how are you hosting it? iis? docker? lambda?

Comment: @DanielA.White in iis and kestrel as reverse proxy

Comment: Thank you @ProgrammingLlama, this library looks promising ,I appreciate your help, but I really don't think adding a third-party library is needed, after all this is a simple requirement, and probably Microsoft have some solution for this perpouse, anyway if I found a way I will post it here